# Makefile with multiple separate *.cpp files to output separate *.exe files in different dir

Tags: c++, makefile

I am stuck, writing my Makefile.
Directory structure:

```
.\
  Makefile
  .\src\*.cpp(s)
  .\bin
```

**Desire:** *What I want to achieve with one `Makefile`*.

**Run: make**

**Output (Terminal):**

```
g++ -g -Wall   -c -o src/program1.o src/program1.cpp
g++ -g -Wall   -c -o src/program2.o src/program2.cpp
g++ -g -Wall   -c -o src/program3.o src/program3.cpp
g++ -g -Wall   -c -o src/program4.o src/program4.cpp
```

**Output (in /bin/)**

```
program1.exe
program2.exe
program3.exe
program4.exe
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
CXX  = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g3 -O0
SRC  := ${wildcard src/*.cpp}
OBJS := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
BIN := $(SRC:src/%.cpp=bin/%)

.PHONY: all

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(OBJS)

bin/%: src/%.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

**Error:**

```
g++: warning: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Comment: You want separate executable for each cpp file? E.g. if there are s1.cpp and s2.cpp, you want s1.cpp compiled into s1.o and linked to executable s1, and s2.cpp compiled into s2.o linked to executable s2?

Comment: @YurkoFlisk, Exectly separate *.exe for each *.cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introductory parts of the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html) describe that `all: $(BIN)` creates a target `all` that depends on a target `bin`.  That means make will try to create `bin`.  Then you have `$(BIN): $(OBJS)` which says `bin` depends on all the object files, so make will try to create all the object files.  Then there's a recipe for that rule that says, after you've created the object files run this command, which links together all the object files into a single program (`bin`).

So make is doing exactly what you asked it to do.

The problem is that is apparently not what you *want* it to do.

In your question you write, *then take the original filenames of each *.cpp and add that to the executable* which I don't fully understand, but I assumed that you want to link all the objects into a single executable, which is what your makefile does.

But then later you write: *How can I output to bin directory and generate the correct executables?*, but you never define what "correct executables" means, and this makes it sound like you want to turn each individual object file into its own executable; that's clearly not what your makefile does.

So before you can tell make what you want, first you have understand clearly what you want so you can write it in your makefile.  And if you need us to help you write it into your makefile, you need to explain it clearly in your question so *we* can understand it.

Cheers!

**ETA**

OK so you want every source file to compile into an object file, then every object file to compile to a separate binary.

First compute the names of all the binaries you want to build:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)

BINS := $(SRCS:src/%.cpp=bin/%)
```

Now make a rule that depends on all the binaries:

```
all: $(BINS)
```

Now make a pattern rule that tells make how to build each one of those binaries:

```
bin/% : src/%.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

Now you're actually done, because make already has a built-in rule that knows how to build a `.o` file into the same directory where the `.c` file lives, so it can figure out how to build the `src/x.o` files on its own.

Comment: Each *.cpp in the `src` is a single program with its own **main**.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Hi, thanks. See my latest edit.

Comment: You didn't use what I wrote.  You added your own rule `$(BIN): $(OBJS) \n $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(OBJS)`.  That's not right and you should delete it.  That is a recipe that tells make that every binary file in `$(BIN)` can be created from **all** the object files, using that recipe which is not even the right compile line (the `-c` option tells the compiler to create an object file, not an executable).

Comment: I want *.obj to be created in `/src/` and the *.exe in `/bin/`

Comment: Yes, I know.  Did you try what I wrote?  That's what it will do.

Comment: I don't understand where, I am supposed to put this stuff? Your lines?

Comment: What you have in your edited question is correct, except you added your own rule `$(BIN): $(OBJS) \n $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(OBJS)` that I didn't have in my answer.  Take those two lines out.  Then it will work.  That rule is wrong, in a number of ways as I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: I get, `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `WinMain'`

Comment: OK.  That is a completely different problem.  Now your makefile is working to try to create the executables that you want it to create in the places you want it created, which meets the criteria of the question you asked.

Comment: However now the compile line that you are providing is not correct so your binaries cannot be linked.  I had assumed that you were able to build these executables by hand successfully and you just wanted to use a makefile for them.  Apparently you're trying to build on Windows, using mingw, not on a POSIX system using GCC as it appears.  You should close this question as resolved and ask a different question about how to successfully compile and link on Windows and be sure to specify _completely_ the environment you're using (compiler, shell, operating system, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SRC:=${wildcard src/*.cpp}
OBJ:=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,${patsubst src/%,bin/%,${SRC}}}
```

to get the list of the object files, and the rule:

```
obj/%.o : src/%.cpp
    ${CXX} -o $@ -c $<
```

for compiling into the right location.

EDIT You have now clarified that each file is a separate main.

```
SRC:=${wildcard src/*.cpp}
BIN:=$(patsubst %.cpp,,${patsubst src/%,bin/%,${SRC}}}
```

to get the list of the object files, and the rule:

```
bin/% : src/%.cpp
    ${CXX} -o $@ $<
```

will write each output as an executable in `bin`. To kick it off:

```
all : ${BIN}
```

Comment: Where, would I put the second part? `all: obj/%.o : src/%.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -o $@ -c $<
` ?

Comment: What is the second part? I don't understand the question. The code in your followup is not legal. Please try out some things before asking. I've pretty much given you the solution to dealing with the directories.

Comment: See my edit for clarity.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer without testing. Please do some testing yourself! You don't learn from asking until someone gives you the perfect answer.

Comment: Hi, see my edit.

Comment: Your `${BIN} : ${OBJS}` rule is not right. Use my compilation rule.

Comment: I want *.obj to be created in `/src/` and the *.exe in `/bin/`

Comment: You don't have to be so **Rude**. I am trying, I am completely *New* to **Makefiles**. I been reading a book today, a few pages. I been googling, and I watched some YouTube videos. *I never wrote that I am an expert on this, did I?*

Comment: "A few pages"? Read a couple pages more.